# Finding the last element with the same class in Capybara and filling it with some text

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I've following markup:

```
<div class='foo'>
  <form>
    <input class='bar' type='text'>
  </form>
<div/>

<div class='foo'>
  <form>
    <input class='bar' type='text'>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'd like to fill input in the second `.foo` container. How I can achieve this in Capybara ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What about:

```
within all('.foo').last do
  find('.bar').set 'a value'
end
```

Check [within](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session%3awithin) and [set](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element%3aset).

Comment: Excellent, I haven't known that `within` accepts node as argument, thanks

Comment: Any Idea How to click a element which is neither first nor last